# Objeto Query no responde al exportar XLSX

Tags: genexus

Me está pasando que al querer exportar a excel desde un query object nunca llega a descargar el archivo.

[image: MenuQuery]

Luego de un rato aparece el mensaje:
[image: PaginaNoResponde]

En la consola aparece este mensaje:

```
gxpivotjs.js?202111510465494:261 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
at xlsx (gxpivotjs.js?202111510465494:261)
at Object.OAT.ExportToExcel2010 (gxpivotjs.js?202111510465494:526)
at Object.<anonymous> (gxpivotjs.js?202111510465494:645)
at gxgral.js?144151:667
at k (QueryViewerCommon.js?202111510465494:66)
at XMLHttpRequest.o (QueryViewerCommon.js?202111510465494:67)
```

Gx16 U11 + java.

Alguna idea?
Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, aparentemente se da cuando encuentra un campo vacío o nulo.
En mi caso son fechas con 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000 ....
Ni idea como puedo resolverlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto que comentas parecería ser un bug que fue solucionado en la versión de GeneXus 17 Upgrade 2 según este [SAC #48887: Error al exportar una Query a XLSX con fechas nulas o vacías](https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=48887;;)

Comment: Uhhh!! No hay ningún WA según veo, voy a tener que exportar de la forma tradicional entonces.  Gracias Eugenio!.